# Python- get parent class function instant variables from within a nested class

Tags: python, function, class, objectinstantiation

I'm having a bit of a dilemma with Python nested classes. What i'm trying to do is get variables from a function at the top level of class A and use them in the sub class B. 
Something like this

```
 class A:
   def function_A():
      value = 5

      class B:
        def function_B(self):
            print (A.value)
```

This method below works if i turn the variable into a class variable like below  but it doesn't do what i want:

```
 class A:
   value = 5

      class B:
        def function_B(self):
            print (A.value)
```

I'm guessing that this isn't possible so can anyone provide a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `value` is local to `function_A`, and exists only while that method is running. There is simply nothing to access when it's not executing, which will be the case when `function_B` is executing. In particular, in your first example it's **not** an attribute of `A`, or of any instance of `A`.

It's not clear from your code what you actually intend to do with such a `value`, so it's difficult to make further suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

The class A has no attribute `value`, because the `value` variable is defined inside the `function_A` function. Therefore you don't have to access `value` as an attribute of the class, but as a normal variable that you can access from class `B`, because it is in the same scope. You have to remove the `A.` before `value`

Example:

```
class A:
    def function_A():
        value = 5

        class B:
            def function_B():
                print (value)

        var = B
        var.function_B()

test = A
test.function_A()
```